# Adding a Controller without corresponding model while using cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, cancan, cancancan

I've added a controller `collaborators` to manage a particular type of join association between `Users` and `Companies`.  The issue is that whenever I load anything from `collaborators`, I get the error

> uninitialized constant Collaborator

From my understanding, this is because there is no model `Collaborator` and I am using `cancancan`for authorization.  From the old cancan (note not cancancan) [documentation](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions#custom-class), I've been able to gather that controllers that don't have a corresponding model need to have a model manually authorized for them something like: `load_and_authorize_resource :the_model, :parent => false`.

This seems to work if I disable `load_and_authorize_resource` in my application.rb controller.

**SO my quesestion is:** what is the best way to authorize controllers that don't have corresponding models with cancancan?  Can I continue to `load_and_authorize_resource` in my application controller?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to edit your question for correctness. The documentation link you have says "If the model is named differently than the controller...", and not "...that controllers that don't have a corresponding model need to have a model manually authorized...", as different model name != no model.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This [LINK](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/changing_defaults.md#non-restful-controllers) will help.

From the link, I quote,

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource :class => false
  def show
    # automatically calls authorize!(:show, :tool)
  end
end
```

And in your `ability.rb`:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :show, :tool
  end
end
```

Comment: you are a life savior buddy. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: How can you adapt it if the Controller is not in the default namespace? Say you have `Admin::ToolsController`, how should the `can :show, :tool` statement be adaped?

Comment: @psychoslave It should be "underscore"-based as opposed to "Camelcase"-based. Run `'Admin::ToolsController'.underscore` in your `rails console`. It should output: `'admin/tools_controller'`. Therefore, you instead use `can :show, 'admin/tools'`. Unverified, but... I remember this works.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to adapt that to the case that concern me, but what I come with didn't solve the problem. I expose my specific case in more details in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527088/how-do-you-authorize-access-to-a-page-dealed-by-a-controller-without-correspondi