# how to set an ability for api resource without model cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, cancancan

My problem is that I do not understand how can I set an ability for resource without model. Since now I have single api controller

```
class Api::V1::ProfilesController < Api::V1::BaseController   

  before_action :doorkeeper_authorize! 

  authorize_resource class: User
  respond_to :json

  api :GET, '/profiles', "This is index for all registered users except current user" 
  def index    
    render json: User.where.not(id: current_resource_owner.id)   
  end 

  api :GET, '/profiles/me', "This is current user profile's data"
  def me    
    render json: current_resource_owner      
  end

  protected
  def current_resource_owner
    @current_resource_owner ||= User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
  end
end
```

In this case Profile is not a model it's only a controller(api resource) Also I have a cancan ability

```
can :me, User, id: user.id
can **index????**, User, id: user.id
```

It wasn't tricky to set an ability for custom *me* action, but how to set it for :index only in Profiles controller( cause I do already have set abilities for UsersController, which also has *:index* action and I do not want to change them )

I'm just a beginner so please forgive me if my explanations are not so straight-forward( I can write some additional explanations if requested) and for my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this: [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763269/adding-a-controller-without-corresponding-model-while-using-cancancan)

Check out this line: `authorize_resource :class => false`