# CanCanCan for custom controllers with not models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan, cancancan

I know how to restrict access for RESTful applications with CanCan in Rails 5.

Some of my actions and controllers are not RESTful.

For example I have a report_controller with a user_report method. There is no model directly linked to this controller/action.

```
class ReportController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

  def user_report

  end

end
```

How can I define an ability in my ability.rb file to restrict access to this action?

Answer (score 0):

In `ability.rb` define a custom ability like this:

```
can :view_reports, MyClass
```

In your `user_report` action, manually authorize against that ability:

```
def user_report
  authorize! :view_reports, MyClass
  # ...
end
```

Also, remove `load_and_authorize_resource` from `ReportController` since you are invoking `authorize!` directly.

Comment: But there is no model 'User'.

Comment: Use a different model or class then. It doesn't really matter because you aren't authorizing against a particular instance.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34763269/adding-a-controller-without-corresponding-model-while-using-cancancan you might want to try to use `false` as passed class value.